# How do I get a successful connection between wordpress on a google Engine VS server to a Google SQL database?

Tags: wordpress, google-compute-engine

Is there an issue getting a standard wordpress site - hosted on google compute engine, to connect to a google SQL database?

Comment: are you receiving any errors, or seeing any unusual behavior? You have to include more details.

Comment: Sorry: I can connect to the google SQL data base from my local machine and from an external server (from google), but I cannot get a database connection using either the root or a new user from a google VM (compute engine). I have whitelisted the ip. It is like the ip is not being recognized. So I am wondering if there is a special step required to conenct from a google compute machine to a google SQL db.

Comment: The answer is service account_scope for sure as per below. Makes sense to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to authenticate from Compute Engine to Cloud SQL. You can set the service_account_scope= to the compute engine instance at the time of creation. You can refer to the following article for more details about the service account scopes for other Google Cloud services https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/authentication.

Comment: Awesome, that's what I am looking for!!

Comment: So I have created a new instance, and added compute r/w and cloud sql permissions, got a static ip, added the IP to the SQL authorization list, and am still getting a connection error...

Comment: Do you by any chance getting the authentication error. If so you need to setup the root password for your SQL instance which is under "Access Control" page.

Comment: And the FINAL solution is - thank sto a google Engineer - is that I am running CentoS and You are running CentOS and the SELinux is configured to not allow connections from apache. This command was the solution:

    sudo setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect on